# Will I have difficulty getting a UK tourist visa to visit my boyfriend?

Tags: uk-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

I have a boyfriend in the UK. He is a British citizen. We've been together for a year, but we haven't met yet. Since he is still depending on his father, and his father won't let him go to Asian countries to meet me, we decided that I will go there and visit him.

Can I apply for a UK visa and tell about our relationship? I will fund myself since he is still studying. I have enough money to book a hostel, but I am afraid because that will be our first time to see each other.

I am employed but don't own any property. I live with my mum and she is a widow. Is that enough proof that I will still go back to my country? I am from the Philippines.

Comment: As with anyone going to meet a boyfriend/girlfriend for the first time, do be aware that some people will go to a lot of trouble to fake a relationship to exploit you. It's good you plan to arrange your own accommodation. If you know anyone else in the UK who you can call in an emergency, that would help as well.

Comment: @user16259 I would go farther than that; I'd move the meet location to the Continent, and get say a Belgian visa instead of UK.  Your choice of locale, no negotiation, pick a small town and land there a few days early and get to know the locals so they're watching out for you.  A UK citizen is an EU citizen and will have no trouble crossing the Channel both ways.  However you will thwart any aim to exploit, since they will not be able to get you across the channel (lacking a UK visa).

Comment: There's probably a 70% ? probability it's just a scam.

Comment: "We've been together for a year, but we haven't met yet" - What you have there is not a boyfriend. What you have there is a *penpal*

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to give a definite answer about your chances of getting the visa. Having a job is good, but visiting a boyfriend might mean you are seen as likely to stay illegally in the UK. There are lots of questions on this site in different countries where couples have done that!

You could apply, or maybe his father would let him go to Philippines if he was going with a group of his friends: if everything is genuine then his father is not unreasonable in worrying about the son going far from home. If it was with 2 friends then they could go sightseeing while you and him spend time together.

Do consider the suggestion from @harper to meet in another European country for your protection and safety. It is a bit complicated but if he is serious about you then he will do it.